# Module '"@angular/core"' has no exported member 'ReactiveFormsModule'

Tags: angular, typescript

How can I solve this issue. It shows up in app.module.ts file in newly created angular project.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pTzKQ.png)

Comment: It's in [`@angular/forms`](https://angular.io/api/forms)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ReactiveForms is not a module of `@angular/core` but of `@angular/forms`. So all you have to do is changing your import statement to the following:

```
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, this issue happens after "npm update".
Try to restart VSCode and check if the issue remains.
More details at:
[angular: Error: NG0301](https://alsdias.blogspot.com/2022/10/angular-error-ng0301.html)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33106969)